# How to use generics with ES6 Map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

My use case is the following, I have 2 generic types (`GP` and `TP`) with each being simple interfaces with `{ prop1: some_type }` and where `TP` has overlapping keys with `GP`.

I want to create a Map inside the `Properties` as class shown below, unfortunately everything I've tried has failed and I cannot define any type information in the format of `Map<type,type>` which have the following requirements: The keys of the map should be properties of the generic types (`GP`and `TP`) and the resulting type of the property should be from `GP` unless it's also found on `TP`.

This is an example of how I use the `Properties` class:

```
interface GP {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

interface TP {
    prop2: ComplexType;
}

class A extends Properties<GP, TP> {
    ...

}
```

Which looks like this:

```
class Properties<G, T> {
    // THIS IS THE MAP REFERRED TO IN THE QUESTION
    protected _state = new Map();

    state(key: any) {
        return this._state.get(key);
    }
...
}
```

Example usage:

```
const a = new A()

// THE PROBLEM IS HERE - HAS NO TYPING INFORMATION
const prop1 = a.state('prop2');
```

Comment: Please provide an example of `GP` and `TP`. `Map` expects two generics, for Key and Value, like this: `new Map<Key,Value>()`

Comment: [In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). This also lacks a clear [mcve]. It's really not clear what your expected output is, etc.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want the `_state` property to be a `Map` that accepts only the merged keys and values of the
generic `G` and `T` types, with `G`'s type taking precedence if a key exists on both.

The short answer is that you cannot apply such contraints to a map.
As @captain-yossarian points out, `Map` accepts a key type `K` and  value type`V`, which won't do what you want:

```js
// the es2015 map interface can constrain key and values separately, but not key-value pairs

interface Map<K, V> {
    clear(): void;
    delete(key: K): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: V, key: K, map: Map<K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    get(key: K): V | undefined;  // any K type is valid as a key, any V type is valid as the value
    has(key: K): boolean;
    set(key: K, value: V): this;
    readonly size: number;
}
```

The good news is that if you remove maps from the equation, it may work as desired.  Define a custom type that merges `G` and `T`.  Set `_state` equal to that custom type.  Here is the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=62&ssc=44&pln=42&pc=1#code/PTAEFkFMCcHNIFAlAWxvAzqALgC0qANaQCeWA9gGagAqAjKAIYB2AJrQEwB0otdA5FgBujADYBXAthIAHKY2JYZ0SAGNIrSM3UIE0uRHSQAPDVCQAHti2ssAJTXlorYxmzQAls1gAaJsxIAPj8aDnMrG3tHZ1d3L19-IMDQAF5QAG8EXl4AbQAFaHI5aGlQLyJSKlpQAB8KkirQgF0ALlACophSy2s2LGIG6jMAflp8wuLpJtA2jsmScN7besaw0dDxzpKSabbmSCEYBABfXWQATXJxaFAAYXJtFWtaWUgscQwNMuYcfHDGFAyURvXReazQSiMdSgADieQyWWyyiKdDabk83gA3IjeMiZBw9uIUAAjGDY056V53ciA4EWGhUtLE8jkYEsUHMcGQ6E0eGZbKgPEE6m0ywMuTk3RIMAAUQsAKBIIQqgeblAIlEHlYUDgkDaOvgxjhITyyTS-KRE1RoAARJQWTafDjBRNhRwnRSVcw1V4NVqDXrDLqjXkTWaEQK8da7Q6nZHXW13JI-MgYIUbgBaF4GfjM1mQFj8MpYZjkbBMDAYDywZiMYnAnDkHBU-jMImk6D8E66L1qv3aowAZQA7owZHJWPqjKZQ7DTakI5aUW0Y+RHc6hW1IaJPimwORCKAs7zQKXhzgFG8XWoNFpobxu2cwABVT6-KSvJ+gAAikEoXikP5blERhKx7EDK3aCYug8N4jRCZILVxQprFUax2AAfTcRhrCnYMYR8GhAmxZ1eyTNCnAAClgNoCJwNoaAASkXAVeDwDwMC4LDsBwghzS4ATsD8ASuFgY4KyDQ0CKI0BkH7CtPhKDwHgkjxRTQTkND8ZFiTrUQFlUFhQFYJtSWwcFfiM9jOIE50KQFbDrEogY2gGKoA3gojmKQ1inmuH5rK4xzIByAYmmxAVTgpaVQFfQCCGA0CMB7VVywAQQXfZzzmGC4ONWhTUo9IoxXfBRFENdtITUAADYauOPxiuq7dPmORiUu9csyoqhc0q4YLKP4KN+GY5AD2VVLvnktI+oG3NGFYOYRtksA0ycIA) version.

**Step 1:  Create a Custom Type that merges the dictionary types**

```js
// Merge
// merges the keys of T1 and T2.  T1's value type takes precedence

type Merge<T extends Record<string, any>, T2 extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [Property in keyof T | keyof T2]: Property extends keyof T ? T[Property] : Property extends keyof T2 ? T2[Property] : never
}

// Your Concrete Types used in the examples

interface GP {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
}

type ComplexType = boolean

interface TP {
    prop2: ComplexType;
}


// Examples

const validMerge: Merge<GP, TP> = {
    prop1: "foo",
    prop2: 2,
}

const invalidMerge: Merge<GP, TP> = {
    prop1: "foo",
    prop2: true, // error - Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'
}

const validMergeSwapped: Merge<TP, GP> = {
    prop1: "foo",
    prop2: false, // ok - TP now takes precedence   
}
```

**Step 2:  Use the Merge type as the state property**

```js
// Define the Class

class Properties<G extends Record<string, any>, T extends Record<string, any>> {
    protected _state: Merge<G,T>;

    constructor(g: G, t: T) {
        this._state = {...t, ...g} as Merge<G,T> // valid assertion as implemented, probably can do better than this...
    }

    state(key: keyof Merge<G,T>) {
        return this._state[key];
    }
}


// Use the Class

const A = new Properties<GP, TP>({prop1: "hello", prop2: 66}, {prop2: false})

const hello = A.state('prop1') // ok
const invalid = A.state('badProp') // error
```